# unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value : swift 2.1

Tags: ios, swift, nsxmlparser, fatal-error

My application was working fine until it is converted into the new Swift ..
I get this error when I test the application in certain views which contains tables

`fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

Here is the function where the app crushes each time:

```
     public func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {

             if(self.hasValue == true && self.beginNewObject == true){
                 print("New employee..")
                 var stf : Staff = Staff();
                 self.staffs?.append(stf);
                 self.beginNewObject = false;

             }

             if (self.currentElementValue == nil)
             {self.currentElementValue = "";}
             switch elementName{
             case "DepartmentName":
                 self.staffs?.last!.DepartmentName = self.currentElementValue;
             case "DepartmentNumber":
                 self.staffs?.last!.DepartmentNumber = self.currentElementValue;
             case "Center":
                 self.staffs?.last!.Center = self.currentElementValue;
             case "Display_StaffResult":
                 print("DisplayResult");
             default:
                 print("default case");
             }

             self.hasValue = false;
         }
```

And I have no idea where to change the code since there is no error!!

Comment: Add an All Exceptions brakpoint then you'll see where the error is thrown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error happened in one of your lines where you force unwrap last property on staffs object:

```
self.staffs?.last!
```

By using ! you say I'm sure there is a data in my optional but unfortunately you are wrong and that's why the app is crushing.

You can change it to:

```
self.staffs?.last?...
```

that's a safety way or do it like that:

```
if let last = self.staffs?.last {
    last.DepartmentName = ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you unwrap `.last!` element which may not exist (empty array or self.staffs doesn't exist).
Try to replace each call to `self.staffs?.last!` with following:

```
if let lastElem = staffs?.last {
  lastElem = ...
}
```

Or add this before your switch and put switch inside this brackets.

Answer (score 0):

replace "!" with "?"

Because you unwrapped some nil value with "!"

Try adding exception breakpoints

Comment: I doubt he can do that on last! cause it is the left value of an assignment.

Comment: @HermannKlecker Yes it's possible. It will assign the value only if the left-hand is not nil. It's called Optional Chaining (same as in Greg's answer).

Comment: Interesting. I'll give it a try. I understood optional chaining slightly different.